# Create Excel Workbook with Office 15 and VS 2012 C#

Tags: c#, office-interop, visual-studio-2012

I tried to create a new excel workbook, but it's doesn't work. I use Visual Studio 2012 with .Net Freamework 4.5 and Microsoft Office 15.

I was looking at these articles:

http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-tutorial.htm

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248531/Export-Excel-File-for-Csharp

If I try to create a `new ApplicationClass("ApplicationClass xlsApp = new ApplicationClass();")`, I get this error:

> "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' cannot be embedded.
>   Use the applicable interface instead."

I using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.

Do you know the solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error clearly states,

> Use the applicable interface instead.

Write `new Application()`.
Even though `Application` is an interface, the compiler will convert this into the appropriate COM activation code.

The error is caused by Embedded PIAs; disabling that (in the reference properties) will also fix it.

Comment: Thank you, but How I do disabled this? Or Where exactly? Thanks your answer.

Comment: Ohh, I find it. If I click the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Properties and set the 'Embed Interop Types' to False, It's works. Thank you.